# Get the exact extent when exporting a PDF with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to export to PDF the extent of my selected feature in ArcGIS pro using arcpy.

My code so far:

```
# Open the aprx project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(APRX_PATH)

# Get the map
m = aprx.listMaps("*")[0]

# Get the layer 
lyr = m.listLayers("MY_LAYER")[0]

# Get the layout
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("*")[0]

# Select some feature in my layer
lyr = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,"NEW_SELECTION","MY_CONDITION")[0]

# Get the mapframe_element
mf = lyt.listElements("mapframe_element")[0]

# Choose the output Height and Width 
mf.elementHeight = 11.7
mf.elementWidth = 8.3

# Set the extent
mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr, True, False))
mf.panToExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr, True, False))

# Clear the selection
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

# Export the PDF
mf.exportToPDF(os.path.join(PDF_PATH,'MAP.PDF'),150)
```

I get something like that

[image]

But i need the exact extent

[image]

How can I avoid the margin in the extent?

Answer (score 3):

You can rescale the extent with:

```
mf.camera.scale
```

So in my case:

```
# Set the extent
mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr, True, False))
mf.camera.scale = mf.camera.scale*0.4
```

I get the exact extent If I multiply `mf.camera.scale` with 0.4.